# "Correct" way to export a cloth simulation as an .mdd file?

Tags: modifiers, export, unity, cloth-simulation

What would be the "correct" process for creating and exporting cloth animations done on "complex" geometry? From my noob experience, it seems the cloth animator is best used with basic mesh's, i.e. a subdivided plane.

**To see what I mean, compare:**

[This](https://gyazo.com/1557b3b57b217b25aaf20759966954e2) shows the result of a simulation done on a subdivided plane with property modifiers **attached after**.

[This](https://gyazo.com/cc4e2a4471f6fc8e22b774f6d8dd4fca) shows the results I got running the animation on the final mesh (**modifiers used before**).

I'd like to be able to use the first method. It works fine in the blender viewport, but I haven't found a way to actually export it. [This is what it looks like after export](https://gyazo.com/ab2eb57f21060f739a3eff8ecc68338c). I'm exporting it as an .mdd file using the "NewTek MDD format" addon. Is it possible to use this sort of process? Or is there a better way of doing it? Ideally this should be an automatic process at export.

Any insights will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

this happens when you import the MDD data and apply to a mesh that is not the same topologically speaking as the one you exported, meaning same number of polygons and topology.

Comment: Okay I think we're on the same page. But just to be sure, does this mean it's exporting the MDD data for just the subdivided plane? If so, what ways are there for me to include the new mesh data in the exported MDD file? I was thinking I may have to go and add a seperate set of keyframes for every frame of the animation, but that either means lots of manual work or perhaps looking into writing a custom script. Hopefully there is some easier alternative.

Comment: most likely you will need to apply the modifiers that change the topology, for example, the Subdivision Surface